# Verificação de correspondência de código em um vetor dentro de uma struct em C

Tags: c, array, struct

seguinte, eu criei uma struct

```
 struct eventos
{
    int codigo;
    char data[11];
    char atracao[50];
    int ingresso;
    float valoring;
};
```

E então, criei um vetor desse modo

```
struct eventos ficha[5];
```

Meu objetivo é verificar dentro de uma função denominada consulta(), se um código fornecido pelo usuário corresponde ao código de um evento já registrado anteriormente (Neste programa, há a possibilidade do registro de um evento e uma das categorias do registro é o código do evento), e então, após essa verificação, eu exibo os dados do evento através de um outra função denominada exibir().
Criei a função consulta() do seguinte modo:

```
void consulta()
{
    printf("Digite o codigo do evento que deseja consultar\n ");
    scanf("%d", &code);
    for(h=0;h<2;h++)
        {
            if(code == ficha[h].codigo)
            {
                exibir();
                system("pause");
                system("cls"); 
            }

                else 
                {
                    printf("Evento nao cadastrado\n ");
                    system("pause");
                    system("cls"); 
                }
        }
}
```

Porém, um problema persiste, toda vez que faço uma busca por um código, se este se encontra nas primeiras posições do vetor, é exibido os dados do evento, seguido de, por exemplo, duas mensagens de "Evento não cadastrado".
De maneira similar, se o código se encontra nas últimas posições, é exibido primeiramente "Evento não cadastrado", para finalmente exibir as informações do evento correspondente ao código inserido.
Gostaria de saber como faço para que o programa quebre o laço assim que ele encontrar um código válido e exibir os dados do evento.
Já tentei utilizar a função "break;", mas de algum modo funciona para o primeiro teste, mas quando, ao cadastrar dois eventos, obtenho sucesso consultando o primeiro e o segundo consta como evento não cadastrado.

Se puderem me ajudar com alguma saída, serei muito grato!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz umas modificações na sua função consultar:

```
void consultar(){
    printf("Digite o codigo do evento que deseja consultar\n ");
    int code,posicao,achou=0;
    scanf("%d", &code);
    for(int h=0;h<2;h++){
        if(code == ficha[h].codigo){
            achou=1;
            posicao=h;
        }
    }

    if(achou == 1){
        printf("%d",ficha[posicao].codigo); 
        printf("Evento cadastrado\n ");                
        system("pause");
    }else{
        printf("Evento nao cadastrado\n ");
        system("pause");            
    } 
}
```

A função agora funciona da seguinte maneira, se ele achar ele soma +1 numa variável e outra guarda a posição.

Se a variável achou=0, não tem esse código no vetor, se a variável=1 existe esse código no vetor.

**O seu erro é:**

Você está fazendo o teste lógico em cada posição do vetor, então se nessa posição tiver o código que procuras, ele vai dar verdadeiro, se não tiver vai dar falso.